# How to long poll this AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, server, polling

I have a click function that triggers a php script through AJAX. The php script starts a video upload to Vimeo. My problem is the Apache server is set to timeout after 5 minutes and I do not have root access to configure this. I can see the uploading takes place for exactly 5 minutes…then crashes…503 timeout error.

How do I long poll the server with this Ajax function? Im trying to keep the server alive for longer than 5 minutes. (Some uploads can take 15+ minutes)

```
$('#videoSubmit').on('click', function() {
    ........
    .......
    $.ajax({
        url: 'create_vimeo_upload.php',
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: video_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function(response){
                   tmpdiv.innerHTML += '<br/>' + response;    
       }
     });
 });
```

Comment: By far the easiest way is to get a server where you can change the timeout time.

Comment: If you have access to PHP code, add `ini_set('max_execution_time',900);` at the start of the script.

Comment: I already set the max_execution time inside the php.ini file to 5000.

Comment: Does Chrome have a timeout of 5 minutes of no activity?

Comment: Adding ini_set('max_execution_time',900) did not help. Still drops the uploading at 5 minute mark